# How can I use a variable used in another unit within a different method?

Tags: delphi

I have a method that requires a local variable processed in another unit, but I don't know how to reference it correctly. Depending on the result of the `if` condition, the variable obtained changes.

```pascal
function Connecting.SendSomething(Var1 : Boolean;Var2 : boolean) : integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if 2+2 = 4 then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 2;
  ...
end;
```

`Result` is only mentioned there. Nowhere else in the unit code was it used, so I'm guessing that's the integer variable. The point is that I want to use `Result` inside an `if` conditional in a different unit's method.

Please bear in mind that the secondary unit is correctly included on top, the names of the variables have been changed to put them here and the code is simplified as to omit sensitive data.

Over there I'm using `Connecting.SendSomething()` inside a basic button's method with `(TRUE, TRUE)` and `(TRUE, FALSE)` values as parameters, I just don't know how to "reel in" `Result`.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Function_Declarations explains what `Result` is and how it works.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know you have a lot of experience here, I just wonder why you posted it as a comment instead of an actual answer. 
Just saw the second comment. Result reflects whether the data was sent successfully or not, in other words. a value of 0 means there were no errors connecting. And a value of 1 means the opposite.

Comment: You'll generally get 1, which reflects 2+2 being 4.

Comment: At the call site (a different unit's method in your case), "result" is reflected by the function call itself. When you write "if Connecting.SendSomething() = 0", the result of the function will be evaluated and returned. The statement will effectively be equivalent to "if Result = 0".

Comment: @JuanFer "*I just wonder why you posted it as a comment instead of an actual answer*" - because sometimes it is just easier to fire off a quick comment and move on, than to post a full answer. I have posted an answer now, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Result` refers to the `integer` that `SendSomething()` returns:

[Procedures and Functions (Delphi): Function Declarations](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Function_Declarations)

> The statement block of the function is governed by the same rules that apply to procedures. Within the statement block, you can use variables and other identifiers declared in the *localDeclarations* part of the function, parameter names from the parameter list, and any identifiers within whose scope the function declaration falls. **In addition, the function name itself acts as a special variable that holds the return value of the function, as does the predefined variable `Result`.**
>
> As long as extended syntax is enabled (`{$X+}`), `Result` is implicitly declared in every function. Do not try to redeclare it.

So, only `SendSomething()` and its *immediate caller* can access the `Result` value, eg

```pascal
if Connecting.SendSomething(true, true) = 1 then
```

Unless `SendSomething()` explicitly passes its `Result` as a parameter to another procedure/function, eg:

```pascal
function Connecting.SendSomething(Var1 : Boolean;Var2 : boolean) : integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if 2+2 = 4 then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 2;
  ...
  DoSomethingWith(Result);
  ...
end;
```